# MonoTouch - reuse UIAlertVIew?

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.ios, uialertview

Should instances of UIAlertView be reused when possible?

Or is wrapping them in a using-block the best practice?

- For one situation, I created a
  (non-modal) MessageBox class (just
  like WinForms or WPF).  I mainly use
  it for convenience.
- Another situation is a custom
  UIAlertView that I've subclassed that
  has more advanced layout.  I wire-up the Dismissed event to do some work on close.

Would either of these situation call for a different approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think there's any problem doing this in a using block - you may want to abstract out the handler so that you dont have alert box delegates all over the place that do the same thing.

then again the LoadingHUDView is a good example of needing to code out the functionality for more advanced things...

but either way - if you're reusing the same object but really changing it each time - there;s not much to be gained IMO

Comment: I agree with @CVista.. the uialertview is so lightweight that there's little gain for saving the object for later.. I usually just use it inside a block and that's good enough.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you could make your UIAlertView modal:

To do this, what you can do is to run the mainloop manually.   I have not managed to stop the mainloop directly, so I instead run the mainloop for 0.5 seconds and wait until the user responds.

The following function shows how you could implement a modal query with the above approach:

```
int WaitForClick ()
{
    int clicked = -1;
    var x = new UIAlertView ("Title", "Message",  null, "Cancel", "OK", "Perhaps");
    x.Show ();
    bool done = false;
    x.Clicked += (sender, buttonArgs) => {
        Console.WriteLine ("User clicked on {0}", buttonArgs.ButtonIndex);
    clicked = buttonArgs.ButtonIndex;
    };    
    while (clicked == -1){
        NSRunLoop.Current.RunUntil (NSDate.FromTimeIntervalSinceNow (0.5));
        Console.WriteLine ("Waiting for another 0.5 seconds");
    }

    Console.WriteLine ("The user clicked {0}", clicked);
    return clicked;
}
```

Comment: Would a better solution be to use ManualResetEvent in conjunction with the anonymous method?  while(true) with a sleep seems pretty bad to me.  Also seems off-topic from the question, which is if UIAlertView reuse is worth it or not.

Comment: You need to pump events, so you must call into NSRunLoop.Current.Run or RunUntil.   But the iOS method from breaking out of a Run method does not work, which is wh the pump needs to be used with a timeout.   Your approach will merely block and not even updated or paint.  Try it out for yourself.

Comment: You're right, b/c this is running on the UI thread.  At first it just looked like a (bad) while(true) Application.DoEvents() that I've seen people do in WinForms.  Sucks that you have do this on the iPhone, b/c there is no ShowDialog() that will create a nested message pump.

Comment: This causes the app to freeze (can't press the buttons and the while loop just keeps going) in at least 2 situations that I know of 1. Display the UIAlertView and then rotate the device, or 2. If you display the UIAlertView from an EntryEnded (i.e. validation that requires input), but you just clicked on an element that would cause scrolling to occur.